# Select values from table which not match predefined

Tags: php, mysql

I have several values, generated from PHP. Like 1, 10, 15, 17, 20.
Also I have a table with several values, like:

```
id
1
3
10
12
15
```

I want to write a query, which will give me all numbers, which do not exist in table `id` column.
In my example, values of `17` and `20` should be returned.

Comment: @SashiKant 17 and 20 were both not present on the list of ID. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 10, 15, 17, 20)
```

Which will get you those which are in your set.

And then use some PHP array function to get the substract of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

it will be much easy if you store those numbers in a temporary table so you can do join, eg

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    temporaryTable a
        LEFT JOIN tableWithNumbers b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae804/1)

Comment: yes, get all IDs from your table and do checking of existence through loop

Comment: on PHP level? And if I have millions records in DB and need to check only several numbers? I think it will work much more faster on mySQL level..

Comment: yes, that is why if i were you i'll insert them on temporary table. `:D`

Answer (score -1):

You can use IN for that:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (1, 10, 15, 17, 20)
```

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)